# Python Table Alignment/Padding?

Tags: python, alignment

I have a function that currently takes a list and creates a table counting the number of times each item occurs in the list. When I run it with single character items, the frequency column is returned in a nice even line. But when the item is more than one character, then the frequencies are all off of alignment. How can I fix this in Python?

Here is a picture of what the result looks like (since I cant figure out how to make a table...) with these two examples:

[image]

```
freqTable([1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 5])
```

and

```
freqTable(['CIS', 'CIS', 'CIS', 'J', 'Psy', 'Psy'])
```

How can I fix the alignment?

EDIT: Its made up of 3 functions

```
def drawTable(freqD):

    iteml = list(freqD.keys())
    iteml.sort()

    title = 'ITEM' + (' '*2) + 'FREQUENCY'
    print(title)

    for item in iteml:
        print(item, ' '*3, freqD[item])

    return None

def genFreqTable(alist):

    freqD = {}

    for item in alist:
        if item in freqD:
            freqD[item] += 1
        else:
            freqD[item] = 1

    return freqD


def freqTable(alist):

    freqD = genFreqTable(alist)
    drawTable(freqD)

    return None
```

Heres the test cases
freqTable([1, 2, 3, 4])
freqTable(['CIS', 'CIS', 'CIS', 'J', 'Psy', 'Psy'

Comment: Where is your function? How does it look like?

Comment: What is `freqTable`?  Please show your code.  Please paste the *text*, not an image.  This is so we can copy the text and try it ourselves.

Comment: do...forgot to add that. Editing right now

Comment: By the way, `1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 5` are not single characters, they are integer objects.

Comment: added the code and the text for the test cases

Answer (score 0):

You must use formatted output for printing, e.g.:

```
print("%-4s\t%3d" % (item, freqD[item]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit confusing about naming two tulpes, the same name `freqTable`.

```
freqTable([1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 5])
```

and

```
freqTable(['CIS', 'CIS', 'CIS', 'J', 'Psy', 'Psy'])
```

normally the last declaration will override the other one.

about

```
#tuples and lists are the same thing, but a tuple cannot be changed
# a list variable : [] or <varname> : mylist
mylist : list = [] 

# a tuple : () or <varname> : mytuple
mytuple : tuple = ()
```

---

**Proper alignement of the elements in a table :**

---

with color by *`colorama`*:

```
from colorama import Fore, Style


coins = [
    ["NAME", "#", "Price", "Change (%)"],
    ["Bitcoin", 1, "$7,430.07", 1.22],
    ["Ethereum", 2, "$461.02", -3.43],
    ["XRP", 3, "$0.46150", -3.90],
    ["Bitcoin Cash", 4, "$804.32", -1.70],
    ["EOS", 5, "$8.11", -4.29],
    ["Stellar", 6, "$0.29635", 0.91],
]

dash = "-" * 60


def color(val):

    if val > 0:
        out = Fore.RED + str(val) + Style.RESET_ALL
    else:
        out = Fore.GREEN + str(val) + Style.RESET_ALL
    return out


for i in range(len(coins)):
    if i == 0:
        print(dash)
        print(
            "{:<15s}{:>6s}{:>20s}{:>15s}".format(
                coins[i][0], coins[i][1], coins[i][2], coins[i][3]
            )
        )
        print(dash)
    else:
        print(
            "{:<15s}{:>6d}{:>20s}{:>21s}".format(
                coins[i][0], coins[i][1], coins[i][2], color(coins[i][3])
            )
        )
```

without color (remove the import *`colorama`*)

```
def color(val):
return str(val)
```

output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
NAME                #               Price     Change (%)
------------------------------------------------------------
Bitcoin             1           $7,430.07        1.22
Ethereum            2             $461.02       -3.43
XRP                 3            $0.46150        -3.9
Bitcoin Cash        4             $804.32        -1.7
EOS                 5               $8.11       -4.29
Stellar             6            $0.29635        0.91
```

vs

```
------------------------------------------------------------
NAME, #, Price, Change (%)
------------------------------------------------------------
Bitcoin, 1, $7,430.07, 1.22
Ethereum, 2, $461.02, -3.43
XRP, 3, $0.46150, -3.9
Bitcoin Cash, 4, $804.32, -1.7
EOS, 5, $8.11, -4.29
Stellar, 6, $0.29635, 0.91
```

REF - more information:

- [table alignement](https://blog.softhints.com/python-3-how-to-print-colors-and-tab-aligned/)
- [from lists to dataframe](https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/01/how-to-create-pandas-dataframe-from-multiple-lists/)
- [formatting](https://pyformat.info/)
  or google